# Passing an array from the success response of a js controller to ci controller

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I have just started learning angularjs .

I have a doubt on Can we pass an array from the success response of a `js controller` to a `ci controller` where Im loading a view page.On that view I am using this array result.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you don't need to call CI view while using AngularJS, Just write an API in CI which will accept data and respond JSON output. See the angular's [HTTP](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service for sending data to server.